# Explicitly Specifying Lambda Parameter Types in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I am learning Lambda of c#, say I am Having:

```
void Foo<T> (T x)         {}
void Bar<T> (Action<T> a) {}
```

Are the following 3 expressions exactly the same thing?

```
Bar<int> (x => Foo (x)); // (1) the comment is 'Specify type parameter for Bar' 
Bar ((int x) => Foo (x)); // (2)
Bar<int> (Foo); // (3) the comment is 'As above, but with method group'
```

Comment: *exactly the same*; a mathematician would argue you mean *equivalent*, since, at least, the syntax is different ;-)

Comment: *Currently*, the second one creates a new delegate each time it executes, whereas 1 and 3 *can* be cached by the compiler. (If everything is static, I believe it *will* be cached.)

Comment: @elgonzo sorry I changed original the expression order. You mean the 1 and 2 are same?

Comment: Let me rephrase it (taking your edit into account): (1) and (2) are two lambdas, resolving into an anonymous method. In those both cases, a delegate to this anonymous method is passed as parameter. In (3) a delegate to the Foo method is passed. As long as the identity of the delegates itself does not matter, the resulting behavior and parameter are equivalent - a delegate with which to call the Foo method. However, if identity of the passed delegate matters (for example, using it to subscribe/unsubscribe to/from an event), all three delegate would need to be treated as different/unique.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I guess you mean third one, not second.

Comment: @Evk: It was right when I wrote the comment - the OP has reordered them... but yes, the method group conversion result isn't currently cached.

Comment: @elgonzo thanks a lot for your clear clarification!

Comment: @elgonzo I am wondering in the third case, could we actually using it to subscribe/unsubscribe to/from an event? As I don't even know the delegate name as you mentioned was passed in as parameter? How can others using it to subscribe/unsubscribe to/from an event in that case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I find the parameter name is 'a'

Comment: @bean, i am not sure if i understand you correctly. A delegate itself has no name - it is just a reference to a method (it doesn't matter if the method itself has a name or is an anonymous method without a name). The variable(!) holding such a delegate has a name (like the parameter `a` in your example case above)  If you have a delegate that matches the signature of an event, you can subscribe/unsubscribe such a delegate to/from this event. (contd.)

Comment: For example, lets say some object has an event `SomeEvent` using `SomeEventArgs` (i.e., a matching event handler has the signature `void SomeEventHandler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)`), then nothing will stop you from doing something like this: `Action<object, SomeEventArgs> a = ...;`, `SomeEvent += a;`, `SomeEvent -= a;`

Comment: @elgonzo I understand now. your clarification is really helpful. I appreciate your time on help to clarify this for me. Thanks again :-)